# restrict site access if not authorized + DIV advice reflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope to explain what I need in a clear way.
I have a site (which uses Javascript and Jquery) which should be accessed only by customers who are in good standing with payments, and I recognize them reading a server side database.
The mechanism works pretty well, but there is a minor problem which should be addressed.
After the validation check, if further site access must be blocked I use the following brutal code to show a message in a DIV (id=noway) and then stop any operation:

```
$("#noway").html("<p>You are not allowed to proceed since your payments are overdue</p>");  
while 1{}
```

Problem: the DIV does not show anything until the browser's (mozilla) timeouts with a 'script in the page has stopped...continue..exit...' message.
It seems that Mozilla enters the infinite loop before of completing the DIV update. What can I do?

Besides this, is there any other more elegant way to block any further visitor activity?
Actually I thought to redirect the visitor to a different page with just the advice, but I would prefer not to do in this way, if possible.
Thanks

Comment: that `while` doesn't make sense. Is there more of it? If not it is an infinite loop. It is preventing repaint in browser. Only way to prevent site access is through server by not delivering content

Comment: By the way it's also invalid syntax because there's supposed to be a parenthesis after the `while`, around `1` (i.e. `while (1)`).

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to restrict site access is to do it server-side. Your page shell read the server-side database before it build any client-side output. So, if the user is not authorized, than the only page content shell be the message about the payment. And only if the user is OK, then the page outputs all the regular contents.

Comment: Yes, this is something I thought, but I would prefer to show to customer what he COULD have if he pays. The fact is the page has a lot of buttons and fields, and noone should be operative. That is why I chosen to prevent any action by forcing an infinite loop (a part the wrong syntax, as noted, which is typo). Unfortunately I discovered the ugly windows message and that the div which is not refreshed until the script stops. Possibly I will have to follow your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Anyway, the infinite loop is a bad idea. If you want to show the buttons and fields, but prevent using them, I would suggest using a _disabled_ attribute on them, like this:
`<input name="myfield" disabled >`
You also can add this attribute to all controls at once using javascript.